# Forms - Clone form with different url + theme

Tags: forms, theming, uri

I have a content type which can be created by admins and regular authenticated users.
Now i would like to create a separate form url like /city/create for authenticated users instead of the standard admin url /node/add/city.

I try to achieve to have two urls for the same form with two different layouts.

Could you guys point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can create path(url) alias for this. Using alias the same url will be called.
Regarding theme you can alter form with some condition to assingn different theme.
e.g.

`function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if(SOME_CONDITION){
  $form['#theme'] = 'FORM_THEME1'
 }else{
  $form['#theme'] = 'FORM_THEME2'
 }
}`

Comment: how about the layouts?